# What causes your hood to be attacked?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I've been capturing hoods quite successfully. In realistic case, the more hoods I own, the higher effort will be required to defend them though. So I decided to ask here:

What factors decide which hood will be attacked and by whom? Possible candidates:

- Random chance
- The fact that you recently attacked/captured hood
- Proximity of enemy hood to attacked hood
- Number of hoods captured

I need to know which ones are involved and how in order to develop ideal strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience in the game, having a hood attacked is a random event that can occur at any time.

This seems to be supported by the [wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Gang_Warfare_in_GTA_San_Andreas):

> ... the **random factor** of territories coming under attack (which may occur while the player is engaged in another activity).

Regarding who will attack the hoods, I was unable to find anything on the wiki, but based on my anecdotal experience in the game, hoods are attacked and 'reclaimed' by the original owners of the hood (for example, if you take a hood from the Ballas, it would be Balla gang members who attack and try to reclaim the hood).

Don't worry though - if you're looking for a strategy for defending your territories. there are a number of different strategies available. One that I would recommend is simply continuing to take over hoods until you control all the hoods in the game. According to the wiki:

> Taking over all of the other gangs' turf in Los Santos will mean that the Grove Street Families have completely taken over Los Santos; **the player's territories will no longer be attacked.**

There are a number of [tips](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Gang_Warfare_in_GTA_San_Andreas#Tips) the wiki also provides for doing this efficiently while also minimising the risk of death, including dating [Katie Zhan](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Katie_Zhan) (which will allow you to be revived without losing your weapons), using vehicle side missions to avoid having to defend your hoods (especially useful if the hood is very far away), and an exploit involving the mini-gun from [Mike Toreno's Ranch](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Mike_Toreno%27s_Ranch).

Comment: Could you expand on the vehicle side missions? Does side mission stop the attack? Several times I saved game during the attack. The hood remained under my possession, but the green color was lighter, possibly indicating reduced influence.

Comment: Sure - if your hood is under attack, you can start a vehicle side mission, like Paramedic, and this should stop the hood from being attacked. In your case, a lighter shade of green would indicate lighter presence, so if you are experiencing this I would recommend trying a vehicle side mission and seeing if you get the same result. I can add this to my answer if you'd like.

Comment: Possibly interesting observation: if a region is attacked and you load earlier savegame (long before attack), the same region will be attacked, suggesting it's either seeded or chosen immediatelly after last defense mission ends.